# How to write IF(expr1,expr2,expr3) in mssql

Tags: sql-server, case

There is IF(expr1,expr2,expr3) in my sql.

How to accomplish it in MS SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
CASE WHEN expr1 THEN expr2 ELSE expr3 END
```

By the way, this syntax isn't SQL Server specific - it also works in MySQL and most other databases.

Comment: To add to your answer, IF in t-sql is never used in a select, update, insert or delete stament, it is only used to control the flow of stamenets.

Comment: Pair When/Then is repeatable. So it's more like if/elif/else construct